# application listening to only ipv6 when started for first time, starts listening to to ipv4 when started again

Tags: c++, tcp, merge, mfc

I have a dicom listener application. When I launch it for the first time it listens to ipv6. If I launch it again while it is already running (bound to ipv6) it listens to ipv4. So now I have two instances of the application, one listening to ipv4 and the other one to ipv6.
If I start the application when the application is not already running, it is bound to ipv6 only.
In my advanced settings, I tried unchecking the ipv6 component and then then starting the application but still the application starts in ipv6.
I verified this by checking it using command netstat -ao | find "PID"

Can someone suggest the reason for this behavior?

myMergeStatus = MC_Wait_For_Association("Store_Query_Service_List",1, &aCalledAppId, &anAssocId);

Comment: What behavior? You have state at least two distinct scenarios and observed behaviors. Which are you interested in? And why? What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: The port is available and working perfectly. I have even checked the issue by disabling the firewall. There is no issues in the host file.

When I checked the config files of mergecom, I have found that in Mergecom.pro file, IP_TYPE is havingvalue as 'AVAILABLE'. It means that it will listen to both IPv4 and IPv6. When I change this 'AVAILABLE' to 'IPv4' manually, my application listens to IPv4. My problem is, I have another version of my application and in it IP_TYPE is 'available' and still the application listens to both IPv4 and IPv6. Could you suggest the cause now?